# Are certain types of device not patentable?

Tags: device, paranormal, supernatural, ghost, equipment

After watching one too many ghost-hunter type shows, I had an idea for a detection device. I've built and tested a prototype and am looking to patent. I do understand an actual device isn't necessary anymore but I wanted a proof of concept.
My question is this -  I cannot determine if this category of device is even patentable. Does the Patent Office allow a submission of this type? Most, if not all, equipment used in that type of endeavor is designed for another use and just happens to be used for ghost hunting. Haven't had much success in trying to figure this out...

thanks in advance!

Comment: Phrase it as a measurement device and they'll never even question it. What does it matter, what phenomenon you are trying to prove by measuring whatever it is you are measuring?

Comment: That makes sense, yes. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual mechanism is novel and not obvious you can patent it as a novelty device or possibly as a detector of "fields". An example is [US 9517421 Device for fanciful detection of ghosts](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9517421B1/en) and [US4971592 Toy ghost detector device](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4971592A/en).

Adding [US9858041B2 Systems and methods employing unique device for generating random signals and metering and addressing, e.g., unusual deviations in said random signals](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9858041B2) It includes a disclaimer -

> Among other things, as described herein-below, it is noted that the various embodiments herein do not rely on the paranormal phenomena for legal utility under 35 U.S.C. 101, but that, by way of example, the mere possibility or theoretical potential or belief in a user thereof can also achieve very valuable uses and benefits, from education, to helping focus attention, to amusement, to reminders, and more, as the reader will appreciate based on this disclosure.

This patent might be a good source to inspire verbiage about things that are phenomena not yet understood by science.

If you say it can detect ghosts you will be rejected for lack of utility, like a perpetual motion machine. Analogously, there are numerous "novelty" perpetual motion machines that have been patented in the U.S. It is fun to watch them spin or whatever they do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, but here is my take on your question. To qualify for a patent, an invention needs to be novel, non-obvious and useful. I think your main challenge will be the demonstration of usefulness. I and many other scientists and engineers don't believe ghosts exist. I'm not saying I know for sure, but I've never seen convincing evidence. If ghosts don't exist then there is no useful purpose of a ghost detection device.

I did try a search go Google Patents. Unfortunately "ghost detection" is a common phrase for image and audio artifacts. I did find [US9517421B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9517421B1/en) titled "Device for fanciful detection of ghosts" but this is described as a novelty toy.

You might want to read the [Wikipedia article on Ghost Hunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_hunting). There is a section on "Methods and equipment". If any of the things listed there are similar to what your device uses they may represent prior art.

Comment: One of the requirements in the European Patent Convention is that the invention is "susceptible of industrial application", which it is "if it can be made or used in any kind of industry, including agriculture". The same argument of your response regarding usefulness would be used by the EPO to eventually refuse the patent application.

Comment: @theEuropeist This is useful info. You should make it an answer.

Comment: This is pretty much what I found, too, leading to my dilemma. My equipment measures none of those, so still a possibility I think. Thanks!